# How can I count how many times a shell script is run (for local conan versioning)?

Tags: linux, shell-script, version-control

I'm looking for a way to do version control on my conan package, locally (note that I'm new to `conan` and usually the reference used by my working place is the `CI_PIPELINE_IID`).

I was thinking of doing a script that does: `make`, `make install`, and `export-pkg`.

I was thinking of having an environment variable that gets incremented with each use of the script, or having a file with the number in it, that I would have to read and write to increment it. I wanted to know opinions since I'm fairly new to GNU/Linux.

Comment: Why not Git?...

Comment: What do you need: just a unique number, or a monotonic sequence?

Comment: You can't do it with an environment variable. Try writing a script that changes one.

Comment: we do use git as CI_PIPELINE_IID comes from using a CI/Cd pipeline, I was looking for a way to have version locally (before pushing to git which has its own versioning).

Comment: Just a unique number would be find

Answer (score 0):

Counting the runs is a terrible way to do versioning. You should seriously look into `git` or other versioning tools.

Using a shell variable (or environment variable if you wish) will work if you run always in the same shell. When you log-out and back in, you get a new shell. When you start a second terminal screen, that is a new shell too.  So that is the limitation.

Using a file is relatively easy:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f "$1" ] ; then
        echo 0 > "$1"
fi
read value < "$1"
newvalue=$((value+1))
echo $newvalue>"$1"
echo $newvalue
```

If more than 1 user increments, you should probably do some locking et cetera.

Comment: Thanks! we do use git, I was looking to keep track of a .so locally in between the git push.